# Order of operators in Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I was solving one question and came across the below expression

$\{ \forall x, \alpha \rightarrow (\exists y, \beta \rightarrow (\forall u, \exists v, y) \}$

My query was, that does the comma here means the below expression?

$\{ \forall x( \alpha \rightarrow (\exists y(\beta \rightarrow (\forall u, \exists v, y))) \}$

Comment: The usual convetion for omitting parentheses is: "$∀$ and $∃$ apply to as little as possible." In this case, we have to assume that the comma "," replaces a parentheses. The ambiguity you have noticed shows that there is no benefit in using commas and parentheses.

Comment: @Mauro-didn't get you :(

Comment: If we omit ",", the for mula reads : $∀xα → (∃yβ→(∀u∃v \gamma))$. Thus, if the comma has a role at all, is to replace a parentheses : $∀x(α → ∃y(β→(∀u∃v \gamma)))$.

Comment: My comment above is : the first formula in your post has 4 commas and 3 parentehses and is ambiguous. My last formula has 6 parentheses and is readable. Conclusion : use all the parentheses needed for a full readibility of the formulas. In addition both formulas in your post do **not** match the basic rule : **as many closed parentheses as open ones**.

Comment: Having said that, the only way to avoid useless discussion is to rely on the syntactical specification of the formal language: what are the rules used for "," ? See e.g. Rosen, page 45 for the notion of *scope*.